# Dates in the Modified Column

Tags: document-set, modified

In a document set how do I change the date under Modified from days, i.e., 5 days or 22 days to `MM/Day/Year`.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the list settings and then enter the settings of the specific column.

- If you choose Display Format to `STANDARD`, then it will be displayed as a normal date.
- The second option  - FRIENDLY - displays a date format to "few seconds ago" or "2 days ago" for example.

Please note that the final format can change due to `regional settings`.